# Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined - using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've got issues accesing some of the data returned by api.
When I assign data using setPosts(data) like this

```
useEffect(() => {


   axios.get("https://api.randomuser.me/")
   .then(res => {
     console.log(res)
     const data = res.data.results["0"]
     setPosts(data) })




 },[])
```

into here :  `const[posts,setPosts] = useState({data: []})`

I can use this in  `<div>{posts.gender}</div>`

But when I try to go one step lower, `<div>{posts.name.first}</div>` , I get the error as in the title.
When I check the console, I can see all the data is there.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your effect, you're setting an object that describes a user to your state `posts`, e.g.

```
{
  gender: "female",
    name: {
    title: "Miss",
    first: "Nicoline",
    last: "Løvli"
  },
  location: {
  ...
}
```

However when you create your state in `const[posts,setPosts] = useState({data: []})` - you're setting an object `{data: []}` to `posts` as a default value.

During your first render, the user's data is not retrieved yet from request, so the component is still using `{data: []}`.

When `<div>{posts.gender}</div>` is rendered - it is not failing because in this case `posts.gender` value is just `undefined` - you're trying to access field `gender` from object `{data: []}`. 
So it renders an empty `div`.

At the same time when `<div>{posts.name.first}</div>` tries to render - `posts.name` is also just `undefined` and you're basically trying to access field `first` from `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Knowing what you wrote I was able to add if clause :  <div>{!posts.gender ? (
  <div>loading...</div> ) : ( 
  <div>{posts.name.first}</div>
  )}</div> ... so if posts is empty, it writes loading.. for a split second and then it renders correctly...  I find this solution a bit dirty though, can you suggest a better one?

Comment: @PeterSlanina at first I'd suggest not to set `{data: []}` to posts, but `null` or an empty object (having `data` field is confusing, it will disappear after you'll set a real data from the request). at second - probably it's better to check not for `posts.gender`, but for `posts.name` as soon as you're accessing `posts.name.first`. also you can write `<div>{posts.name ? posts.name.first : 'loading...'}</div>` instead.